# Question regarding declaration of equality operators in C#

Tags: c#, operators

This seems incredibly basic, but I couldn't find any other answers on this particular note.  In declaring a `==` operator in C#, you must also declare the `!=` operator.  Obviously every case may vary based on type, but if a type has explicit equality or does not, is it reasonable to declare `!=` as simply `!(a == b)`?  Is there a reason NOT to do this?  For example:

```
    public static bool operator ==(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return ((p1.X == p2.x) && (p1.Y == p2.Y));
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return !(p1 == p2);
    }
```

Comment: It's OK. [How to: Define Value Equality for a Type (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type)

Comment: The obvious answer is that, in x86 assembly,  `a != b` is done in two instructions (`CMP` and `JNE`) while `!(a == b)` is done in three instructions (`CMP`, `JE`, and `NOT`)

Comment: @RezaAghaei - thanks!  Makes sense.  @Powerlord - since `==` compares two fields in this case... would this make my implementation of `==` be `CMP` `CMP` `JNE` and `!=` be `CMP` `CMP` `JNE` `NOT`?  Would it be four total operations either way with two comparisons?

Comment: You would not do this if two things that are unequal are not necessarily not equal to each other. Examples: two calculations that underflow may be neither equal to, nor unequal to, each other. May also be true of NaNs, infinities, N/As, NULLs.

Comment: @DourHighArch oh for sure - definitely only for explicitly binary equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good example from Microsoft Docs: [How to: Define Value Equality for a Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) covering important aspects of defining equality for types.

In the following example, for `x!=y` you see it's simply returning `!(x==y)`:

```
using System;
class TwoDPoint : IEquatable<TwoDPoint>
{
    // Readonly auto-implemented properties.
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    // Set the properties in the constructor.
    public TwoDPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        if ((x < 1) || (x > 2000) || (y < 1) || (y > 2000))
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Point must be in range 1 - 2000");
        }
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as TwoDPoint);
    }

    public bool Equals(TwoDPoint p)
    {
        // If parameter is null, return false.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(p, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Optimization for a common success case.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, p))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If run-time types are not exactly the same, return false.
        if (this.GetType() != p.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match.
        // Note that the base class is not invoked because it is
        // System.Object, which defines Equals as reference equality.
        return (X == p.X) && (Y == p.Y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return X * 0x00010000 + Y;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(TwoDPoint lhs, TwoDPoint rhs)
    {
        // Check for null on left side.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
            {
                // null == null = true.
                return true;
            }

            // Only the left side is null.
            return false;
        }
        // Equals handles case of null on right side.
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TwoDPoint lhs, TwoDPoint rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}
```